# Start table view at top after app becomes active

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want my table view to scroll to the top after my app becomes active, but I want to do this before the view actually displays. Is this possible?

Here is my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive{

[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

}
```

This works, however you can see the table view jumping to the top, so it is actually executed after the view has appeared. Using `viewDidAppear` would work, but that method is not called when the app is becoming active from the background.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to scroll it to top every time app resign active? In this:

```
optional public func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)
```

When user come back, he/she won't see any animation.

Comment: Unfortunately scrolling is based on an interactive notification, so I can not scroll before the app is actually being  opened, but great idea!